# There is a mode to run a nodejs backend on android?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js

I will try to explain better, I made a NodeJS backend with integrated react UI that call localhost for local API/function integrated in NodeJS. Is there a way to make a porting of this solution to an APK? For now the only way to make NodeJS works on android is manually or with obsolete library like Androidjs

Comment: You could likely compile NodeJS to an ARM architecture but I'm not sure sure how well that will work.

For iOS, it's against the terms of service to run any JavaScript engine outside what Apple already provides you (which is JavaScriptCore). NodeJS compiles against the v8 JS engine so it would break that contract.

Comment: I imagine it's a good way i'm searching a lot but there is no example/material... for the iOS i know it's a problem i suppose but i want to try to realize it at least for android

Comment: Android is kind of a closed system. Unless you root your device, normal app processes don't have direct access to many OS/system APIs. This I suspect would be a problem even if you could compile Node and natively link it against your app.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The right answer after some research is the comment of Norman Breau

"Android is kind of a closed system. Unless you root your device, normal app processes don't have direct access to many OS/system APIs. This I suspect would be a problem even if you could compile Node and natively link it against your app."

Answer (score 1):

There is an Library. You can check [nodejs-mobile](https://code.janeasystems.com/nodejs-mobile). If you want Node.js in root process can you check [Magisk Node.js](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Alt-Repo/node)

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use Node.js using Termux however it is not quite recommended to run  a backend server on Android.

Comment: Sorry, but i thinks it's not a solution to create an APK with integrated nodejs server